# Exists any way (or advice) to speed-up c#/WPF projects build?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I have the application (solution in VS2010) with +-10 projects. Some of these projects are quite large (dozens of folders and hundreds of files).

When I make a change in project on lower level and I want to run my tests (+-10 seconds) then I have to wait 2 minutes for projects build.
This is very inefficient.

Is there any way to speed-up build? For example, split current projects into multiple projects or something else?

Or are there some general advice and recommendations to speed-up building projects in Visual Studio?

Comment: My instinctive response - only rarely test high level components, and do it on a schedule of at most twice per day. Use low-level unit tests for the nitty gritty stuff.

Comment: Split up your projects into multiple solutions, based on the frequency of changes.
For example, if you have some projects where you won't be making frequent changes, keep them in a separate solution, and target the frequently modified projects into a single solution, and test projects in another.

Comment: @Sandeep That would make refactoring an absolute nightmare, unless you *also* had a solution with all projects, specifically used for that purpose. But then you'd have to maintain three solutions and that'd be a chore and a half as well.

Comment: @J.Steen: Yeah, I agree. Another way might be to disable the "Build" option for the projects you actually don't want to build. For example, I guess you don't want your test projects to get built every time you Build the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience solutions with large number of projects build slowly on vs2010 and there is not much you can do about it:

1. Reduce number of projects - larger single project will build faster then many smaller.
2. Prepare set of build configurations Build->ConfigruationManager to build only parts of your project since you don't have to build projects that depend on changed project if public interface is not changed. This can be tricky to use and some unexpected errors might occur in runtime. Also make sure that all your projects point to single `Bin\Debug Bin\Release` folder so that new dlls are loaded on application start. This is requited because if you don't build project its dependencies wont be copied to its output directory.
3. Upgrade to vs 2012. This is the best option you can choose.

Comment: Do you have any experience with speed-up after upgrade to VS 2012 (or a link)?

Comment: Yes we have recently migrated to vs2012 and as a whole it is faster. Note that many things add up for build performance and overall experience (e.g. addins tend to slow things down). For solution 31 projects on the same machine for a rebuild process I got about 1/3 improvement. More over the vs1202 feel is much better for instance the annoying window "Processing requests from the background thread" almost never appears.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:
Go to "Tools" menu -> "Options" -> "Projects And Solutions" -> "Build And Run" 
And increase the value of "Maximum number of parallel project builds" to 32 or greater.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use tools that allow concurrent test execution coupled with shadow building - NCrunch or MightyMoose. 
Also try to get rid of unused references - for example move all tests that test only your core project to separate project so that they get executed right after core is built. Try not to use MS accessors, because they force to fully recompile all projects that they are referencing. And of course use SSD disks.